# finding the x and y coordinates for every angle

Tags: python, math, physics

I am trying to make some code that finds the coordinates of a satellite in orbit, but I am currently trying to do it for just a circle where you ignore gravity etc. and you are already given the radius. I have already tried this code but the loop wont work please help

```
import math

r = 5

angle = 0

while angle <= 360:

    angle = math.radians(angle)

    x_coord = math.sin(angle)*r

    y_coord = math.cos(angle)*r
    print ("Position [",x_coord,y_coord,"]")
    angle +=1
```

Comment: Although an answer has already pointed out the problem here, in future please specify what you mean by "won't work" in the context of a piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

When the line `angle = math.radians(angle)` executes, this is replacing the value of the same `angle` variable that's being checked on the previous line - thus, since `angle` will never be higher than 360, the loop will never finish.

My recommendation is to change the name of the variable when you convert it to radians, so that you're not overwriting its value - such as like this: `angle_radians = math.radians(angle)`. Thus, you'd also have to change your `sin` and `cos` to use the new variable as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, as pointed out by @Random, you need to use a different variable name for  `angle = math.radians(angle)`. For example, `angle_radians`

Second, when you use `print`, you need to convert `x_coord` and `y_coord` to string: `str(x_coord)` and `str(y_coord)`

Try this:

```
import math

r = 5

angle = 0

while angle <= 360:

    angle_radians = math.radians(angle)

    x_coord = math.sin(angle_radians)*r

    y_coord = math.cos(angle_radians)*r
    print ("Position [",str(x_coord),str(y_coord),"]")
    angle +=1
```